# S3 lifecycle configuration to expire only files and not folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this, but I would like to expore only files withing folder and leave folders empty...

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "ID": "MyID",
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "Prefix": "",
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 30
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you wish to retain the 'folders'? Folders do not actually exist in S3. So, just pretend that they exist and everything will work as normal.

Comment: Yes but the client who is using this space uses FTP client to browse files and there the objects that have child objects are presented as folders... So he wants to retain those, just delete all child objects...

Comment: In that case, the desire to keep folders seems not to be compatible with using an S3 Lifecycle to delete objects.

Answer (score 3):

There is typically no folder. It's inferred from a collection of objects with the same key prefix. For example if objects with keys `dogs/fido.png` and `dogs/buddy.png` exist, then a virtual 'folder' named `dogs/` is inferred to exist (but it doesn't actually exist, in the typical S3 case).

If you want a given folder to continue to exist after all S3 objects with the relevant key prefix have been deleted then you would need to explicitly create an object representing the folder e.g. `dogs/`. But typically you would not do this as it's rarely needed (and it's *never* technically required).

For example, if you listed objects with the prefix of `dogs/`, the result might be as follows (2 objects):

```
dogs/fido.png
dogs/buddy.png
```

or it might be as follows (3 objects):

```
dogs/
dogs/fido.png
dogs/buddy.png
```

Typically, in fact in almost all cases, the former is what you actually have in practice: 2 objects, not 3 objects.

You *could* have the latter if someone, or some process, had explicitly created an object with the key `dogs/`, but it's not typical. You might see this if, for example, someone used the S3 console to 'create a folder'.

For more, see [Organizing objects in the Amazon S3 console using folders](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html).

Comment: Yes that I know. So in the case of `dogs/`, `dogs/fido.png`, `dogs/buddy.png` I would need to apply the Expire policy only to `dogs/fido.png` and `dogs/buddy.png` objects, and leave `dogs/` alive.

Comment: No, you can't do what you want afaik. The lifecycle operates on an S3 prefix e.g. `dogs/` which will expire everything at or below that prefix (including any folder object at `dogs/`). Even if wildcards were supported, which they're not, `dogs/*` would also include `dogs/`. The point I'm making is that this won't work. I think you're going to have to re-create this `dogs/` folder object if you really need it for SFTP or think about solving this in some other way.

Comment: Ok then I will create a cron...